# Installation of private python package from feed in Azure Artifacts automatically uploads repo packages to feed

Tags: azure-devops, python-packaging, python-poetry

I published a private python package in a AzureDevops feed to use in in a different Repo in the same AzureDevops project. The other Repos use poetry as python dependency manager.

The upload of the private package and the import to a different Repo went fine. The issue here is, that when i execute

`poetry install`

in the Repo all dependencies from the pyproject.toml will also be uploaded to the feed.

How can i install dependencies from the pyproject.toml including my private package to the Repo without uploading all dependencies to the feed?

I deleted the dependencies from the feed since they are not needed. Unfortunately they reappear in the feed, when i execute poetry install in the local Repo.

Comment: Hi @bball1195, have you checked my answer below? If you have any question feel free to let me know. If it's helpful for you, in order to let others who have the similar question with you know this answer more clearly, it's suggested that you accept my answer below according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you create your feed, you have checked "Include packages from common public sources".
[image]

Go to "Feed Settings" -> "Upstream Sources", you can see several public sources added as upstream sources in your feed:
[image]

When you run install/restore, if there is no corresponding package in your feed, it will download it from the upstream sources and save a copy in the feed. Therefore, we don't need to download these packages again the next time we use them.

It should be noted that when you install, all dependencies required in your project will be downloaded. Therefore, you will see the project's dependencies in your feed. If you don't want the dependencies to be cached in the feed, you can disable the Upstream Sources, but you will need to upload all the dependencies needed in your project to the feed. Otherwise, you may get the error like `could not found the dependencies`.

You can also see this info from the official doc [Azure Artifacts Upstream Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops#:%7E:text=Once%20you%27ve%20enabled%20upstream%20sources%2C%20any%20package%20installed%20from%20these%20upstream%20sources%2C%20a%20copy%20will%20be%20automatically%20saved%20to%20your%20feed.).